# C++ function with function parameter more elegant

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers, parameters

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int m_value;
public:
    A(int value)
    {
        m_value = value;
        funcA(&A::param);
    }

    void funcA(void (A::*function)(int))
    {
        (this->*function)(m_value);
    }

    void param(int i)
    {
        cout << "i = " << i << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    A ob(10);

    return 0;
}
```

I have a class in which I call a function that receives another function as parameter. The function call is at line `funcA(&A::param)`. What I want is to be able to pass a function as parameter without being necessary to specify the class scope: `funcA(&param)`. Also I didn't want to use `typedef`s that's why I have the code a little 'dirty'.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Comment: It is just an experimental example. The useful thing in this is a little complex and it's too much to explain. It can be applied if this class is made to be inherited so the user can pass functions as parameters easier.

Comment: Well however complex the application of what you're intending to achieve, it's most likely less confusing than what you've shown here. Just show us what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done. A function pointer in a class must be identified using the class scope (A::function)

Answer (score 0):

That is kind of ugly.

The first thing you should look at doing is recoding things to use inheritence and dynamic dispatch instead. To do this you change the A class to have a virtual method that funcA calls

```
class A {
...
    void funcA () {
       custom_function(m_value);
    }
protected:
   virtual void custom_function (int)=0;
}
```

Now for every different custom_function you want to use, you declare a new class derived from A, and implement the function in there. It will automagically get called from funcA:

```
class A_print : public A {
public:
    virtual void custom_function (int param) { 
       std::cout << "param was " << param << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If that isn't flexible enough for you, the next best C++-ish solution would be to implement a [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses) (an object that acts as a function, possibly even overriding the `()`operator.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why you can't just do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int m_value;
public:
    A(int value)
    {
      param(value);
    }

    void param(int i)
    {
        cout << "i = " << i << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A ob(10);
    return 0;
}
```